# Avoid Text jiggling in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, beta

Any idea to avoid the jiggling below? The code is something like this:

```
Text(format: "%02d:%02d", hours, minutes)
    .frame(width: 100, alignment: .trailing)
```

[image: jiggling]

(The frame is bigger than the string)

NOTES:

- The problem is that "1" is thinner than "0" so when I hit a combination like `01:11` the total length of the string is smaller than (let's say) `00:00` and the text is displaced.
- Fixing the frame width has no effect on the jiggling.
- Alignment `.trailing` or `.center` don't fix the jiggling.
- I am curious about the `...` that appears from time to time. I can fix it by adding a whitespace at the end of the `String` like this `"%02d:%02d "`

The slider code (for completion):

```
Slider(value: $totalTime, in: 0...9).frame(width: 150)
```

The conversion from Slider value to hh:mm:

```swift
func formatTime(_ time: Float) -> String {
    let hours: Int = Int(time)
    let minutes: Int = Int(time.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0) * 60)

    return String(format: "%02d:%02d", hours, minutes)
}
```

Comment: Why not just set a fixed `minWidth`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please post a more complete code snippet? Ideally it should be everything in the `View`

Comment: I can see the same issue in apps like itunes. The difference is that their font is very small so it might not be important. In my case, the text has a bigger font, so the jiggling is quite obvious

Comment: Hi  @LinusGeffarth... Yes I tried with minWidth and width, but no success

Comment: You could always use a monospace font :P

Comment: This looks similar to an issue I had when text is changing and animating simultaneously (FB7253222). Any chance you have animation associated with that text view? If so, try removing the animation and see if that fixes it. You should be able to target the animations on the views that need it so the text can lay out properly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can tell it to use monospace digits like this:

```
Text(String(format: "%02d:%02d", hours, minutes))
    .font(Font.body.monospacedDigit())
    .frame(width: 100, alignment: .trailing)
```

You can substitute "Font.body" with your preferred Font.

Comment: That fixed the horrible jiggling ‍♂️

Comment: You can apply `monospacedDigit()` directly on the Text view as well